# Search T(current date/todays date) dated files from a folder with different prefix and different extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am looking for T(current date/todays date) dated files in particular folder.
    C:\Users\abc\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX.

There will T -1, T -2... files will also be there.

And there will be T dated files starting with prefix(NP and PN) and followed by date like `PN27022014` and `NP27022014`.

Also there is another condition, both file will be ending with 5 different extension like

```
PN27022014.TRN
PN27022014.BAL
PN27022014.NEG
PN27022014.NBL
PN27022014.EFG
NP27022014.TRN
NP27022014.BAL
NP27022014.NEG
NP27022014.NBL
NP27022014.EFG
```

I have query to check file with single prefix and ending with single extension.

```
@echo off
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b

set TODAY=%day%%month%%year%
echo %TODAY% 


for /F "tokens=1" %%a IN ('Dir "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\PN*%TODAY%*.TRN"  /-C/S/A:-D 

2^>nul') Do Set y=!n2! & Set n2=%%a
echo out %y%

If %y% gtr 1 ( echo 4 ) else ( echo 3 )
```

How to get it for both prefix with different extensions.

Query should give output 4 if there are files with each prefix and each extension greater than 1.

Comment: I can't follow your question enough to figure out what you want.  What is a `T` file, for example?

Answer (score 1):

This will detect the number of files that match todays date filespec and tell you if 10 files are found, or not.

Date routine requires XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%DD%%MM%%YYYY%"


for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /b /a-d "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\??%datestamp%.*" ^|find /c /v "" ') do (
    if %%a EQU 10 (echo 10 files are present) else (echo incorrect number of files)
)
```